# Span-wrapping multiple occurence of cout's "<<" using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am able to wrap `cout` having a single occurence of `<<` like this one:

```
cout<< "hey"; abc cin>>x; cout<< "hey";abc cin>>x;
```

But i was unable to wrap it properly when it is something like this:

```
cout<< "hey" << "men";abc cin>>x; cout<< "hey" <<"men"; abc
```

**Regex**

```
text = text.replace(/(cout\s*(&lt;&lt;[^;]*)+;)/g, '<span class="group">$1</span>');
```

**See**: http://jsfiddle.net/3N4AE/23/

Comment: What output do you expect this `replace()` to generate?

Comment: 2nd block: <span class="group">cout<<"hey"<<"men";</span>

Comment: That is what the second block is generating. I tested it in RegexBuddy and it came out just like you said.

Comment: @extraRice I noticed after checking the fiddle, sorry for that. Nevertheless Itay's solution may break at some points and it has some flaws.

Comment: @extraRice I've edited my answer with a better code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was that the `semicolon` in your regex finds also the semicolon in the `&lt;` special char.

Fixed by using the following regex:

```
/(cout\s*(&lt;&lt;.*?)[^(&lt;)];)/g
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/3N4AE/26/)

Comment: What is `[^(&lt;)]` suppose to mean ?

Comment: Actually No. It matches any character not an `&`, `l`, `t` or `;`. In other words it doesn't negate the entire sequence `&lt;`.

Comment: @Itay To tell you the truth, it is not in my head right and to be more frank, it is one nasty problem because the text between `<<` symbols can be a string, variable, etc and it is pretty hard to find a way to make it work using a regex. Just think of what a string could contain :)

Comment: @Itay Sorry to inform you that it still won't work, just try putting a semicolon `;` in the string that contains `hey` for example.

Comment: @Itay Ahhh Sorry again, just try putting another `;` in the string somewhere and see what happens. Itay this is really really hard, just think about all the tings that can come between `cout` and `<<`. A string by itself can contain a lot of possibilities.

Comment: @sniffer I've already deleted the link because I found some problems.